# Is there a way to make a generic cheese sauce?

Tags: sauce, cheese

***Scenario***: I have some nuggets, and thought it would be nice to dip them in some cheese sauce. I do not have that, but I thought I could make one with the ingredients I have. But I am not sure if there is a way to make a ***MORE OR LESS*** **generic** cheese sauce.

This is the cheese I have:

[image]

Ingredients in dutch: **melk*** (milk), zout (salt), zuursel (starter culture) and stremsel (which is Rennet, I am not sure what kind of cheese that is).
**My main idea was melting the cheese with an amount of butter, salt, and maybe some milk or cooking cream.** (No need of quantities right now but more of the process to follow).

I think that adding flour would be like making a cheesy bechamel, and I don't know if that is good to dip (or put on top of nachos, whatever is fine, as a cheese sauce, it's nice anywhere). But maybe flour is necessary for this process (specially if the cheese may be quite generic as well).

Comment: "cheesy bechamel" is what I think of as a "generic cheese sauce".  Also known as a "mornay sauce".  And the starch helps to keep the cheese from breaking.  (although there are other ways, like in making American cheese)

Comment: Oh okay! I guess I have seen more liquidy cheese sauces and I have not been that used to it! But in the research I have done so far, there is flour (making this cheesy bechamel as I described it hahaha). I guess I did not see it often, that is why I find it strange! Thanks! @Joe

Comment: It's just a matter of what ratios you use (roux vs. milk vs. cheese) on how liquid it is ... and what temperature, as it'll thicken as it cools.  Also see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47015/67

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Cheese sauce' is really anything semi-liquid that tastes a bit like cheese & can be poured or dipped, depending on how liquid.

Some fast ideas:-

Camembert, brie etc - put it in the oven for 20 mins. Cross-cut the top, dip.
tbh, you can do this with most cheeses, just the French-style crusted cheeses provide a cool looking container.

Generic roux - oil or butter in a saucepan, add the same quantity of flour. Combine 2 mins, add milk slowly, stir. Add cheese, stir, serve.

Welsh rarebit - throw cheese, flour, milk, beer, worcestershire sauce in a pan, heat & stir until it's homogenous.

There's not really much you can do to hot cheese to spoil it ;)
The only two cheeses I can think of that don't work are haloumi & paneer, because they're both pre-cooked & don't melt.

Answer (score 1):

Your "cheesy bechamel" is a classic cheese sauce. It works best with a fairly full-flavoured cheese in the usual proportions, but you can adjust the ratios successfully for flavour and texture. Served hot it's good as a topping or dip, though keeping a dip warm can be a hassle.

With the pictured cheese I'd probably make the bechamel a little on the thin side, then add plenty of cheese, but if it gets too thick you can always add a bit more milk. Personally I'd also add black pepper and a pinch of mustard powder (not enough to make it taste of mustard, just to enhance the flavour). I don't infuse the milk when I make cheese sauce this way.